# Trigonometric Uncertainty Propagation

Tags: trigonometry

> I have $$tan (\frac{2.05 × 10^{-4}± 2.89 × 10^{-6}}{2})=\frac{x}{667.6 × 10^6}$$
>   $$\therefore x = (667.6 × 10^6) \cdot tan(\frac{2.05 × 10^{-4}± 2.89 × 10^{-6}}{2})$$

I want to find $x$ with the absolute uncertainty. I don't know how to start, as I am unsure how I would propagate uncertainties with $tan$. Please include your working out when you explain the method of propagating uncertainties in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general rule is if you have a function $y=f(a,b,c,\cdots)$ and the inputs $a,b,c,\cdots$ with associated errors $\delta a,\delta b,\delta c,\cdots$ then the error in $y$ is given by:

$$\delta y=\sqrt{\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}\cdot\delta a\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial b}\cdot\delta b\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial c}\cdot\delta c\right)^2+\cdots}$$

In the case of $y=\tan x$ this becomes:

$$\delta y=\sec^2x\cdot\delta x$$

Hence

$$\delta\tan(1.025\times10^{-4}\pm1.445\times10^{-6})=\sec^2(1.025\times10^{-4})\times1.445\times10^{-6}=1.445\times10^{-6}$$

and so

$$\delta x=667.6\times10^6\times1.445\times10^{-6}=965$$

So $x=(6.8\pm0.1)\times10^4$ if write the error to only one significant figure (which is common).

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> With
>   $\left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcl}
> \ds{a} & \ds{\equiv} & \ds{2.05 \times 10^{-4} \over 2}
> \\[1mm]
> \ds{\delta a} & \ds{\equiv} & \ds{2.89 \times 10^{-6} \over 2}
> \\[1mm]
> \ds{\widetilde{x}} & \ds{\equiv} & \ds{667.6 \times 10^{6}}
> \end{array}\right.
> $

\begin{align}
\tan\pars{a \pm \delta a} & =
\tan\pars{a} +
\bracks{{\tan\pars{a} \pm \tan\pars{\delta a} \over 1 \mp \tan\pars{a} \tan\pars{\delta a}} - \tan\pars{a}}
\\[5mm] & =
\tan\pars{a} \pm
\underbrace{{\sec^{2}\pars{a} \over 1 - \tan\pars{a} \tan\pars{\delta a}}\,
\tan\pars{\delta a}}_{\ds{\delta x \over \widetilde{x}}}
\end{align}

---

$$
\color{#f00}{x} = \widetilde{x}\tan\pars{a + \delta a} =
\widetilde{x}\tan\pars{a} \pm \delta x =
\color{#f00}{6.8429 \times 10^{4}\,\,\, \pm\,\,\, 9.64682 \times 10^{-2}}
$$

Answer (score 1):

If I properly understand, you face an equation looking like $$\tan(a\pm\epsilon)=\frac x b$$ which gives $$x=b\, \tan(a\pm\epsilon)$$ where $0<\epsilon << a$.

What I would do is to expand the rhs as a Taylor series around $\epsilon=0$; this would give, giving $$x=b \tan (a)\pm b   \sec ^2(a)\,\epsilon+O\left(\epsilon^2\right)$$ which gives $$\Delta x=\pm b   \sec ^2(a)\,\epsilon$$